# Tap to click still on for some applications despite disabling it in 14/15.04

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, tap-to-click

I've had this problem in Trusty, and continue to have it in Vivid. Though I've disable 'tap to click' in system settings, it is still on, but only for some applications.

For example, in evince and in 'About Computer', a tap is still registered as a click. The same happens in the file select box that comes up for sending documents by bluebooth, but not for other file select boxes(saving/opening documents).

What's frustrating is that the behaviour consistently appears for the same applications, yet there seems to be know identifying characteristics of these.

`synclient MaxTapTime=0` does nothing. Output of `synclient | grep Tap` on startup is:
`MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 67
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
TapButton1              = 0
TapButton2              = 0
TapButton3              = 0
TapAndDragGesture       = 1`

Is there any conjecture about the nature of the problem?